# Decoding and comparing JSON with accented char

Tags: json, delphi

I have an IntraWeb app. In the HTML template, I have Javascript creating a JSON document.

This JSON is sent to the IntraWeb backend and I receive the JSON as:

```json
{"order":"Razão Social"}
```

I parse the JSON and put `"Razão Social"` in a var `_order`.

My problem is when I try to compare that value with a string, it fails. I am having some problem with the encoding. The line

```
if uppercase(_order) = 'RAZÃO SOCIAL' then
```

is always false.

I put a breakpoint and I can see the accented char is not OK.

[image]

```pascal
 s:=aParams.Values['xorder'];
 if s<>'' then begin
 jso := TJSonObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s),0) as TJSONObject;
 try
  jso.TryGetValue<string>('order',_order);
 finally
  jso.free;
 end;
end;

if uppercase(_order) = 'RAZÃO SOCIAL' then
 _order:='Order by A.razao_social ';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UpperCase` supports ASCII characters only. Instead compare string case insensitively using [`AnsiCompareText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.AnsiCompareText) or [`AnsiSameText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.AnsiSameText), which are aware of Unicode.

Comment: Hi, David. I just tried if AnsiSameText(_order,'RAZÃO SOCIAL') but no look. It results false.

Comment: I also to tried "if _order.ToUpper()='RAZÃO SOCIAL' but I have the same problem

Comment: I checked the bytes and the problem seems the space in "RAZÃO SOCIAL". From server the space has coded as (160,0) after apply ToUpper() e from local var is (32,0). If I get rid off the space the problem is solved. How could I fix it?

Comment: @LuizAlves 160 is Unicode codepoint [U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm), 32 is [U+0020 SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm). Two very different chars, so it makes sense that they would not compare as equal. Fix the server, it is using the wrong kind of space char

Comment: Hi Remy. This value is comming from intraweb TIWCombobox. It has the values: "ID " and "Razão Social". My html template page has meta charset  UTF-8. Any tip to fix it?

Comment: I just see intraweb inserts a &nbsp in the select option as:  <option SELECTED="" VALUE="1">Razão&nbsp;Social

Comment: David solution is ok, because the problem is comming from intraweb server. Thank you Remy as well

Comment: @LuizAlves IntraWeb generates HTML not plain text. This is not "fixable" because there is nothing wrong there.

Comment: Knowing that you have that problem with spaces, why don't you do an StringReplace before comparing strings ?.

Comment: @LuizAlves the HTML data in the ComboBox has a no-break space in it, so it makes sense that the JSON would have a no-break space in it, too. Where is IntraWeb getting the data from that it is using to populate the ComboBox? You need to follow the data back to its source and then fix it from there. Otherwise, try updating the IntraWeb code to fix the space when translating the HTML data into JSON data.